# D3.js: Stop transitions being interrupted?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with D3.js. I've got transitions working nicely, but I just have one problem: if a second transition starts before the first one ends,

This is a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kqxhj/11/

It works fine most of the time - CDG and LAX get appended and removed as the data changes - but if you click the button twice in rapid succession, you'll notice that the new elements don't appear.

This is the meat of my code:

```
function update(data) { 

  var g = vis.selectAll("g.airport").data(data, function(d) { 
    return d.name;  
  });
  var gEnter = g.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {    
    return "airport " + d.name;
  });
  // Perform various updates and transitions... 
  [...]

  // Remove exited elements. 
  g.exit().transition()
    .duration(1000)
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 1.5*h + ")");
  g.exit().transition().delay(1000)
   .remove();
}

d3.select('#clickme').on("click", function() {  
  update(current_data); 
});
```

I've tried to add some debug statements to figure out what's going on, but all I can see is that when it happens, the exit selection has 4 elements in, not 3 - I don't understand why this is.

Is there a way, either in D3 or in basic JavaScript, that I can ensure the transitions don't overlap?

Comment: You need to listen for the [`end` event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each) and only start the next transition after it occurs. Alternatively, look into [`transition.transition()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-transition). Here's a [great article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#life-cycle) you should check out.

Comment: Also, the remove happens at the end of the transition, so you don’t need to create two exit transitions just to remove the nodes. See the [transition.remove documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-remove).

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE: Since the version 3.5 of D3 (October 2014), it is possible to perform concurrent transitions on elements through the use of [named transitions](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5d8039fb983a29e2ad49). You simply have to add a different name to each transition.

Comment: I found this useful. When adding two transition with the same name to an object the transitions are exclusive, i.e. the second interrupts/cancels the first transition.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

What's going on is that data representation "re-enters" before it has been removed from the DOM (because your remove() call is chained on a transition). However, if the data representation hasn't been removed from the DOM yet, the enter() selection will not contain that data because it already exists! And yet, your transition will continue to execute, and your data representation will disappear without having the chance to "re-enter".

What you need to do is give the exiting elements some sort of identifier. For example:

```
g.exit().classed('exiting', true);
```

Then, when you update your selection, if an element "re-entered", cancel the exiting transition and bring it back to its original state:

```
g.filter('.exiting')
    .classed('exiting', false)
    .transition() // new transition cancels the old one so that remove() isn't called
        .attr('foo', 'bar'); // return to original state
```

I've tweaked your fiddle to demonstrate the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hX5Tp/

Here's a stripped down fiddle to demonstrate the issue (and solution) clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/xbfSU/

Comment: This approach was clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In D3, newer transitions always interrupt and override older transitions. You might address your design problem by using [the each() method within your selection.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) e.g.

```
d3.select('.animated')
.transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr({
    ... // Change something
})
.each('end', function () {
    d3.select(this)
    .attr({
        ... // Change something else, after previous transition
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how I would apply that to my specific case, though - you mean something like append the `each` method to my update transitions, then put the exit transition inside that `each` call?