# Hover transition stops initial transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm working on a radial histogram chart with d3.js.

The issue is as follows: I have an initial transition that makes the bars "grow" to their actual height (eyecandy).

That all works fine. Now I want to add a hover transition, i.e. the opacity of all items should transition to .5 on hover and back to 1 when the hover state ends.

That also works fine on its own.

It stops working fine if the hover state is triggered while the initial transition still takes place. Then the initial transition simply stops and the bars do not reach their final height.

**Question**: How can I make both transitions work together, so that the hover transition doesn't stop the initial transition?

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uavexct/). And here is the code on its own:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
    var margin = {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0
        },
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var arcMin = 150;
    var arcMax = 250;
    var pi = Math.PI;

    var color = d3.scale.category10();


    var data = [
        {
            "value": 20,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 24,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 9,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 93,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 82,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 56,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 29,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 6,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 10,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 4,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 45,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 25,
            "category": "category1"
  },
        {
            "value": 26,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 53,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 60,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 87,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 77,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 40,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 12,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 80,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 23,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 53,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 26,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 34,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 79,
            "category": "category2"
  },
        {
            "value": 98,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 1,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 13,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 80,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 66,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 5,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 36,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 74,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 32,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 4,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 54,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 8,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 64,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 5,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 58,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 41,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 81,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 73,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 20,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 32,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 42,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 55,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 74,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 17,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 6,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 96,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 18,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 1,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 18,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 40,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 9,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 30,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 28,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 25,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 44,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 20,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 99,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 95,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 50,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 65,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 66,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 7,
            "category": "category3"
  },
        {
            "value": 70,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 39,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 12,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 94,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 55,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 15,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 84,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 31,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 48,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 26,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 70,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 30,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 26,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 75,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 43,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 83,
            "category": "category4"
  },
        {
            "value": 64,
            "category": "category5"
  },
        {
            "value": 52,
            "category": "category5"
  },
        {
            "value": 37,
            "category": "category5"
  },
        {
            "value": 11,
            "category": "category5"
  },
        {
            "value": 77,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 94,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 37,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 64,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 92,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 58,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 70,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 47,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 87,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 6,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 87,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 32,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 70,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 38,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 38,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 31,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 82,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 44,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 21,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 78,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 97,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 67,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 29,
            "category": "category6"
  },
        {
            "value": 6,
            "category": "category6"
  }
];


    var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var min = 1;
    var max = data.length;

    var middle = Math.round((max + min) / 2) - 0.5;

    var innerArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(arcMin)
        .outerRadius(arcMin + 10)
        .startAngle(function (d, i) {
            return (i + 0.1 - middle) * (pi / middle);
        })
        .endAngle(function (d, i) {
            return (i + 1 - 0.1 - middle) * (pi / middle);
        });

    var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(arcMin)
        .outerRadius(function (d, i) {
            // Use min-max-normalization to scale value into interval [arcMin, arcMax]
            return (d.value - min) * ((arcMax - arcMin) / (max - min)) + arcMin;
        })
        .startAngle(function (d, i) {
            return (i + 0.1 - middle) * (pi / middle);
        })
        .endAngle(function (d, i) {
            return (i - 0.1 + 1 - middle) * (pi / middle);
        });

    var lines = vis.selectAll(".line")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            return d.category + " line";
        })
        .attr("d", innerArc)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.category);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function () {
            d3.selectAll(".line")
                .transition()
                .duration(300)
                .style("opacity", 1);
        })
        .on("mouseenter", function (d, i) {
            d3.selectAll(".line")
                .transition()
                .duration(150)
                .style("opacity", .5);
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .delay(function (d) {
            return ((d.value - min) / (max - min)) * 500;
        })
        .attr("d", outerArc);
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335781/d3-js-stop-transitions-being-interrupted

Comment: @LarsKotthoff From what I understand, that would work if I want my second transition to start after the first has ended, not on hover.

Comment: Yes, the main point is that newer transitions will always override existing transitions. So in your case you would need to capture the state when the second transition starts and manually merge the transitions (see [here](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/) for pointers), or transition on different elements.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Hm, ok. That doesn't seem worth the effort. Thanks anyway. If you convert that to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Since the version 3.5 of D3 (October 2014), it is possible to perform concurrent transitions on elements through the use of named transitions.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fj0kuoy/1/) you can see the original jsfiddle of the question with named transitions.

```
var lines = vis.selectAll(".line")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return d.category + " line";
    })
    .attr("d", innerArc)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.category);
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function () {
        d3.selectAll(".line")
            .transition("opacity") // NAMED TRANSITION
            .duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseenter", function (d, i) {
        d3.selectAll(".line")
            .transition("opacity") // NAMED TRANSITION
            .duration(150)
            .style("opacity", .5);
    })
    .transition("creation")  // NAMED TRANSITION
    .duration(2000)
    .delay(function (d) {
        return ((d.value - min) / (max - min)) * 500;
    })
    .attr("d", outerArc);
```

Another example from Bostock's page:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5d8039fb983a29e2ad49

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update! Marking this as the accepted answer to keep things up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Transitions that are added after other transitions have started always cancel those earlier transitions, cf. [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions):

> Only one transition may be active on a given element at a given time. However, multiple transitions may be scheduled on the same element; provided they are staggered in time, each transition will run in sequence. If a newer transition runs on a given element, it implicitly cancels any older transitions, including any that were scheduled but not yet run.

And in particular:

> This allows new transitions, such as those in response to a new user event, to supersede older transitions even if those older transitions are staged or have staggered delays.

So the use case you're looking for is *explicitly* not supported by D3.

To achieve what you want would involve capturing the state when the second transition starts and manually merge the transitions (see [here](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/) for pointers), or transition on different elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a d3 "limitation". Transitions cannot run concurrently regardless of whether triggered by hover or by something else.

Try to move the hover transition to CSS, keeping the height transition in d3.

http://jsfiddle.net/w21gunej/

```
.hovertest {
    background: steelblue;
    transition: background 1s ease;
}

.hovertest:hover {
    background: gray;    
}
```

Comment: That would work if I just want to transition one of the bars, but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to my specific problem, I simply delayed the addition of the code that's responsible for the hover effect by the same duration of the initial transition:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    lines.on("mouseleave", function () {
        tip.hide();

        d3.selectAll(".line")
            .transition()
            .duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 1);
    })
        .on("mouseenter", function (d, i) {
            tip.show(d, container.node());

            d3.selectAll(".line")
                .transition()
                .duration(150)
                .style("opacity", .5);
        })
}, 2000);
```

---

For a general solution, refer to the answers of [Pablo EM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30391101/1449199) and [Lars Kotthoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565463/1449199).

Comment: I had a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924360/path-color-goes-black-if-selection-is-made-during-transition I ended up consulting Bostck's transition page: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/ There are some solutions there, the best of which is to be sure to use the right RGB code type.